# How to get raw bytes from ZXing - IPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, barcode, zxing

i have a big problem. I have read some post and can´t solve this problem.
I have a Iphone App, this app read a QR code with zxing, but the QR have a personal encryptation. When ZXing parse this bytes and convert to NSString, the bytes change and i can´t get the originals bytes.

I was reading Decoder.mm and many others classes of ZXing library and i can´t get this.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `ZXWidgetController` and `Decoder` classes aren't set up to make this easy and refactoring them to make it easier is itself not the easiest thing because of the way they were originally designed.

If you wanted to try to patch something in, you just need to go into the `Decoder` class and modify it to grab the byte results instead of the text results in the `- decode` method.

There are some classes in the `objc` directory that might make this particular part easier but they're at a lower level (they are at the `CALayer` level rather than the `UIKit` controller level). And they don't have much documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... i will answer my own question. That what you said is true, ZXingWidgetController think that the returned pointer of char is in UTF8 and make a string with this bytes. What i did? I need the Hexadecimal value of each byte in the string, so if the hexa value of the char 68 is 0x57, i made a string concatenating 57|45|25|a7|7e ...... i convert the hexa value into string format... then i parse that string... is not a good solution but is only what i can do at this moments.

Comment: This is what your encoding in the QR code? So your changing that to something's that's ASCII only? If that's the route you're taking, you might look at base64 encoding. It's standard and it is more space efficient than your custom code.

Comment: Thanks, i thought in base64 encoding but isn`t work because is a custom codifcation, i need to parse the bytes in bits.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to know, how to do that:

I had the same problem (getting raw bytes from the qr-code):

I "fixed" DecodedBitStreamParser.cpp and function

void DecodedBitStreamParser::decodeByteSegment(..) to get a hex-string e.g. ab0cd42...

I replaced the line at the end of the function:

```
append(result, readBytes, nBytes, encoding);
```

with:

```
try {
    char buffer [nBytes * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++) {
        std::sprintf(buffer, "%s%02x", buffer, readBytes[i]);
    }
    append(result, (unsigned char*)buffer, nBytes * 2, encoding.c_str());
} catch (ReaderException const& re) {
    throw FormatException();
}
byteSegments->values().push_back(bytes_);
```